Vue router not redirecting
Yesterday I started working with Vue, Vuetify and Vue Router. With the vuetify project setup the router package was already installed.
First I created some components and basic pages. Then I wanted to implement the routing. To get familiar with it I implemented it for just one item in my NavigationDrawer and it works. Next I wanted to set a route for "/" to display something else than the index.vue page. Didn't work! I tried to create a redirect from "/" to my about page. Didn't work!
index.js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router/auto'
import About from "@/pages/About"
import Home from "@/pages/Home"

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/about'
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    // name: 'about',
    // component: About
    redirect: '/home'
  },
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home
  }


]

const router = createRouter({
  // history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: routes
})

export default router

I played around with the routes but it did not work.
This is my NavigationDrawer component. In my last item I implemented the :to path. This works
<template>
<v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-list class="d-flex justify-center">
        <v-list-item>
            <v-avatar size="128">
                <img src="./../assets/mk1_logo.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar-image">
            </v-avatar>
        </v-list-item>
    </v-list>

    <v-divider></v-divider>

    <v-list v-model:opened="open">

        <v-list-group value="Models">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
                <v-list-item
                    v-bind="props"
                    prepend-icon="mdi-file-document-multiple-outline"
                    title="Models">
                </v-list-item>
            </template>

            <v-list-item title="PvP exact" value="playervsplayerexact"></v-list-item>
            <v-list-item title="PvP overall" value="playervsplayeroverall"></v-list-item>
            <v-list-item title="PvC" value="playervscharacter"></v-list-item>

        </v-list-group>

        <v-list-group value="Functions">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
                <v-list-item
                    v-bind="props"
                    prepend-icon="mdi-toolbox"
                    title="Functions">
                </v-list-item>
            </template>

            <v-list-item title="Add Player" value="addplayer"></v-list-item>
            <v-list-item title="Add Match" value="addmatch"></v-list-item>

        </v-list-group>

        <v-list-item prepend-icon="mdi-chart-bar" title="Player Statistics" value="playerstatistics"></v-list-item>
        <v-list-item :to="{path: '/about'}" prepend-icon="mdi-information-outline" title="About this project" value="abouthisproject"></v-list-item>

    </v-list>

</v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

This is my App.vue. The about page (index aswell) get displayed correctly in the RouterView
<script setup lang="ts">
  import AppBar from "@/components/AppBar.vue"
  import NavigationDrawer from "@/components/NavigationDrawer.vue"
</script>

<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-layout class="rounded rounded-md">
      <AppBar></AppBar>
    
      <NavigationDrawer></NavigationDrawer>

      <v-main class="d-flex align-center justify-center" style="min-height: 300px;">
        <RouterView></RouterView>
      </v-main>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</template>

My problem is, as mentioned above, that redirects don't work and because of that the index.vue is always displayed when loading the page for the first time. Console does not log any errors.
I am a complete beginner in webdev and vue. Maybe I am looking in the wrong places but the docs/infos I read through all implemented in more or less the same way.
I pushed my project to github:
https://github.com/snackbeard/matchup_prediction
Thanks in advance

did you install unplugin-vue-router/vite or did vuetify?  this package implements file based routing.  According to the setup you're not supposed to pass in routes to createRouter, so it looks like you've created a conflict there.  If you want normal vue-router behavior, you should remove this package and delete the plugin from vite.config.mjs

vue-router/auto is magical and causes "routes" to be ignored. I'd recommend to keep away from magical things that aren't thoroughly documented if you want to have control over your own code and don't want to spend time on troubleshooting

@yoduh that worked, thanks. I did exactly what you said and it worked perfectly. Thanks. And I think both came with the "default" package when creating a vuetify project via cli

@EstusFlask I will take a look at that to avoid future problems, thanks
